# Combining CSV files without any headers using batch

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I wish to combine all CSV/TXT files within a directory using a batch script and was hoping you guys could help - pretty new to scripting so please forgive me if I ask for an explanation of what each line does,
I did find something useful however but when tested it still keeps one header row. I hoped it would merge all files - no headers.

for reference:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem configure paths
set "source=C:\Users\Khalid\Desktop\New_folder\p*.csv"
set "target=C:\Users\Khalid\Desktop\newfile.csv"

rem remove output file if needed
if exist "%target%" del "%target%" >nul 2>nul

rem search for header row
set "headerRow="
for %%f in ("%source%") do (
    <"%%~ff" ( for /l %%a in (1 1 10) do if not defined headerRow set /p 
      "headerRow=" )
        if defined headerRow goto haveHeader
    )
   :haveHeader
    if not defined headerRow (
       echo ERROR: impossible to get header row. 
        goto endProcess
)

rem output header to header file to use as filter.
rem header is cut to avoid findstr limitations on search strings
set "headerFile=%temp%\%~nx0_headerFile.tmp"
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
> "%headerFile%" echo(!headerRow:~0,125!
endlocal


rem search for input files with matching headers to join to final file
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('findstr /m /b /l /g:"%headerFile%" "%source%"') do (
    if not exist "%target%" (

            rem first file is directly copied
            copy "%%~f" "%target%" /y > nul 2>nul

        ) else (

            rem next files are filtered to exclude the header row
            findstr /v /b /l /g:"%headerFile%" "%%~f" >> "%target%"
    )
    echo ... [%%~ff] joined to %target%
)

rem remove the temporary header file
del "%headerFile%" >nul 2>nul

:endProcess
   endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way could be

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem configure paths
    set "source=p*.csv"
    set "target=newfile.csv"

    >"%target%" (
        for %%a in ("%source%") do (
            set "headerRow="
            <"%%~fa" (
                for /l %%h in (1 1 10) do if not defined headerRow set /p "headerRow="
                findstr "^"
            )
        )
    )
```

For each input file, read its header and dump the rest of the file. All the output is sent to the output file.

Note that this method has a limitation: the `set /p` can not read more than 1021 characters, if your `.csv` files have longer lines, then, following the   original approach, you can use something like

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem configure paths
    set "source=p*.csv"
    set "target=newfile.csv"
    set "headerFile=%temp%\%~nx0_headerFile.tmp"

    >"%target%" (
        for %%a in ("%source%") do (
            set "headerRow="
            <"%%~fa" (
                for /l %%h in (1 1 10) do if not defined headerRow set /p "headerRow="
                setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
                > "%headerFile%" echo(!headerRow:~0,125!
                endlocal
            )
            findstr /v /b /l /g:"%headerFile%" "%%~fa" 
        )
    )

    rem remove the temporary header file
    del "%headerFile%" >nul 2>nul
```

Comment: The second one works better for me as the script would need to read files longer than 1021 characters. however you said this was a limitation of set /p so why it it also used in the second script?    Also thank you for this solution and thank you everyone else for your input it is greatly appreciated

Comment: @KhalidSheikh, the limitation does not involve the file size but the line length. In the second sample it is used to retrieve at least the start of the headers line, that will later be used as a non matching start of line filter to discard the full line.

Comment: That makes perfect sense thank you for the explanation throughout the answer

Comment: @MCND your first code for me merges the csvs together but in the output csv file, the first 3 lines are stripped! And the first line visible in the output file has had values removed from columns 2 and 3, thus shifting the entire first row left 2 cells.

Comment: @TheoF, If I have to bet, your files lines are LF (`0x10`) terminated. `set /p` reads windows standard CRLF (`0x1310`) terminated lines. So, in your case, `set /p` will not found the line termination it expects, it will read the first 1021 bytes before giving up and the remaining data is sent to output file.

Comment: @TheoF, second code does not keep the file open after the `set /p`  and uses the first 125 retrieved characters as a filter to remove the first line after opening the file again.

Answer (score 0):

If your files have a single line header on line one of each file, and the line order is unimportant:

```bat
@Echo Off
(For %%A In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\New_folder\p*.csv") Do More +1 "%%a")>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\newfile.csv"
```

Comment: There are two possible problems with this approach: 1) `more` command replaces tabs with spaces. 2) In the case of files with more than 65535 lines it requires the user to press a key to continue.

Comment: Agreed, however I would deem it foolhardy to merge files one or more of which had greater than 65535 lines and the OP has provided very little in the way of information with which to make better judgements.

Comment: /Thank you guys, i dont think any of the files i would be merging would have more that 30k lines if i'm honest however. lets just say i had a file with 67k lines would the above method mentioned by MC ND work? also just being curious why is the limit 65535 lines anyway?

Comment: Also, where would you guys learn to script? would love to get as good as you guys